# JQuery toggle/html: changing the content in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, innerhtml

I'm currently working on a blog layout with a main div and a side bar with links. I want **each link to change the content of the main div.**
I tried using toggle and html.

Here's the main class and the content of each link:

```
<div id="main"></div>  
  <div id="works">
      These are my works.
  </div>

  <div id="info">
      About me.
  </div>

  <div id="tags">
      Tag list.
  </div>
```

And the side bar:

```
<div id="mainlink">     
   <button class="linkd" id="butt1"> works </button>
   <button class="linkd" id="butt2"> info </button>
   <button class="linkd" id="butt3"> Tags </button>
</div>
```

*So when I click on the button "works" I want the content of that div into the main div.*

Here's the snippet of the JQuery (that doesn't work):

```
$(function(){  
 $('#butt1').click(function() {
    $('#main').html($('#works'));
    $('#works').toggle();
    $('#info').hide();
    $('#tags').hide();
});

$('#butt2').click(function() {
    $('#main').html($('#info'));    
    $('#info').toggle();
    $('#works').hide();
    $('#tags').hide();
});

$('#butt3').click(function() {
    $('.mainp').html($('#tags'));
    $('#tags').toggle();
    $('#info').hide();
    $('#works').hide();
});

});
```

Note: on my CSS I have the *display: none* as well.

Comment: Instead of assigning the main html to the contents, of each div, you can show and hide each div individually (just remove the line with `.html()`). Also, you may want to use `.show()` instead of `.toggle()` as toggle will not necessarily toggle it the correct way, especially if other functions modify the visibility of the div. https://jsbin.com/viyumejima/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Why not post as answer? @Brian

Comment: @Brian Thank you for the response. But how do I specify that I want it in the main div? (If I remove the .html() it puts the content on the whole page at the very top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the easy way to show and hide `div`s, by assigning a relation to the buttons using HTML5's data attribute (here their `id`s are used in `data-target` attribute). See the snippet below...

```js
$(function(){
  $('[data-target]').on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).siblings().hide().end().show();
  });
});
```

```css
#main > div:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainlink">     
   <button class="linkd" data-target="#works"> works </button>
   <button class="linkd" data-target="#info"> info </button>
   <button class="linkd" data-target="#tags"> Tags </button>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div id="works">
      These are my works.
  </div>

  <div id="info">
      About me.
  </div>

  <div id="tags">
      Tag list.
  </div>
</div>
```